# Error while fetching record using thread in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to run the thread to fetch the result simultaneously from the network on the basis of the query. Below is my code for thread calling

```
 for(int i=0;i<numberOfConnection;i++) 
 { 
      //threadResult[i] = onListen(s[i], toquery); 
      exec[i] = new Thread(() => threadResult[i] = onListen(s[i], toquery));           
      exec[i].Start(); 
 }
```

and `onListen` function is

```
private string onListen(Socket s,string query)
{
string returnmsg = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffff tt"); //= Start Time ===
try
{
Stream ss = new NetworkStream(s);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ss);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ss);
            sw.AutoFlush = true;
            sw.WriteLine(query);
            returnmsg += " " + sr.ReadLine() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffff tt"); //== End Time ==
            s.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        return returnmsg;
    }
```

But I am getting error of index out of range exception.

If I run the same code without using thread like this

```
threadResult[i] = onListen(s[i], toquery);
```

it works. Kindly help me tracking the bug.

Comment: Could you post the code around `exec[i] = new....`?

Comment: exec = new Thread[numberOfConnection];

Comment: I actually aimed at the `i` variable, how do you set it, is it a loop variable and how do you increase it?

Comment: for(int i=0;i<numberOfConnection;i++)
                {
                    //threadResult[i] = onListen(s[i], toquery);
                    exec[i] = new Thread(() => threadResult[i] = onListen(s[i], toquery));
                    exec[i].Start();
                }

Comment: Could you run the program and see what the value of `i` is, then check your `Locals` window and see if `exec`, `s` and `threadResult` collections are big enough?

Comment: Post which C# version. And the exact delcarations for `exec[]` and `s[]`

Comment: Edit the question, do not post chunks of code in the comments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 for(int i=0;i<numberOfConnection - 1;i++) 
 { 
    //threadResult[i] = onListen(s[i], toquery); 
    exec[i] = new Thread(() => threadResult[i] = onListen(s[i], toquery));           
    exec[i].Start(); 
 }
```

Or

```
 for(int i=1;i<numberOfConnection;i++) 
 { 
    //threadResult[i] = onListen(s[i], toquery); 
    exec[i] = new Thread(() => threadResult[i] =    onListen(s[i], toquery));           
    exec[i].Start(); 
  }
```

Comment: Doesn't `threadResult` indexer have to be `index` to in this case?

Comment: Index out of range exception, same issue

Comment: i is detected 1, i dont know why. it must be 0.

Comment: The loop begins with 1?

Comment: Then I didnt understand your last comment

Comment: That 2nd piece of code re-introduces the capturing.